# Large string of numbers becomes scientific form when saving into an SQL database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to save a vary large string of numbers into an sql database and for numbers above about 10 figures, when exporting it, it is in scientific form e.g. 3.5674E15.

With numbers below this there is no problem but I need to export the values from the database in exact form e.g. 45739473920284 and not in scientific form as some of the last few figures are lost.

This is my database adapter:

```
public class DBAdapterWorkouts {
private static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_EXERCISESTRING = "exercisestring";
private static final String KEY_SUPERSETSTRING = "supersetstring";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter2";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CustomWorkoutsDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "customworkouts";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists customworkouts (id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "name string, date long, exercisestring string, supersetstring string);";

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapterWorkouts(Context ctx) {
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapterWorkouts open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String name, long date, String exercisestring, String supersetstring) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EXERCISESTRING, exercisestring);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SUPERSETSTRING, supersetstring);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public void deleteName(int id){
    open();
    String query = "DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ROWID + " = '" + id + "'";
    Log.d(TAG, "deleteName: query: " + query);
    db.execSQL(query);
    close();
}

//---deletes all records---
public void reset() throws SQLException {
    db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null,null);
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + DATABASE_TABLE + "'");
    this.DBHelper.onCreate(db);
}

//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords() {
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE, KEY_EXERCISESTRING, KEY_SUPERSETSTRING}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular record---
public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DATE, KEY_EXERCISESTRING, KEY_SUPERSETSTRING}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {

    }
}
}
```

This is in my activity where the data is saved and loaded from the database:

```
            dbWorkouts.open();
            Cursor c = dbWorkouts.getAllRecords();
            boolean exists = false;
            try {
                if (c.moveToFirst()){
                    do {
                        if (c.getString(1).equals(etxtWorkoutName.getText().toString())){
                            exists = true;
                        }
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (exists){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please choose a workout name that doesn't already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                long date = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                String name = etxtWorkoutName.getText().toString();
                dbWorkouts.insertRecord(name, date, stringExerciseOrder, stringSupersets);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Workout saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w("app", stringExerciseOrder);
            }
            dbWorkouts.close();
```

In the above case, the log produces the number that I am looking to save (a long string of numbers named stringExerciseOrder). The issue arises when I use the following code to retrieve the value.

```
dbWorkouts.open();
    Cursor c = dbWorkouts.getAllRecords();
    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Log.w("app", c.getString(3));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dbWorkouts.close();
```

The output of the second log is in scientific form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Read this: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and look at the types in your create table statement. You have some issues that should then be obvious.

Comment: In create table command replace string with TEXT. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Replace Table create command with this.

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists customworkouts (id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "name TEXT, date long, exercisestring TEXT, supersetstring TEXT);";
```

TEXT is the type in SQLite, which is used for string format.

[List of SqLite data types](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

Try this and update.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much, works perfectly, the link is also very helpful as I'm still fairly new at SQLite